# Unit-Testing PersistenceLayer (JPA/EclipseLink)

Tags: junit

I am not sure what is the correct way of testing my Database, without an prepared In-Memory-Database. I have following TestSuite for JUnit4.

*Ignore the JpaManager, I just need this, because the application runs as a Eclipse RCP and not in a container, nor Spring is used (yet), so I cannot inject an EntityManager-reference and have to handle it manually.*

```
public class CustomerJpaTest {

    private Customer testCustomer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        JpaManager.getInstance().begin();
        // create a new user for testing
        CustomerJpaDao dao = new CustomerJpaDao();
        testCustomer = new Customer();
        testCustomer.setName("Someone");
        dao.persist(testCustomer);
        JpaManager.getInstance().commit();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // remove previously created user
        CustomerJpaDao dao = new CustomerJpaDao();
        dao.remove(testCustomer);
        JpaManager.getInstance().commit();
        JpaManager.getInstance().dispose();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomerSaving() throws Exception {
        // not sure yet
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomerLoading() throws Exception {
        ICustomerDao dao = new CustomerJpaDao();
        Customer customer = dao.findByName("Someone");
        assertEquals("Someone", customer.getName());
    }
}
```

Since I am running on a real database, I am creating my object that I am going to test in the setUp method and remove it after the test(s) are done. **And exactly here is my problem: this setUp and tearDown could be actually also some kind of tests (testCustomerSaving, testCustomerDelete), but when I have the tests running in a particular order then they wont be isolated** (when saving fails, loading fails as well, and then deleting).

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Begin a transaction in `setUp` and rollback the transaction in `tearDown`.

Comment: this is whats actually happening in begin and dispose. But since I am doing a commit after I store it to really be able to load it from the db in the test the rollback isnt deleting the object. Probably this is a wrong way. Would it be sufficient for the test if the oject is loaded just from the JPA-cache, assuming that there is no difference?

Comment: Then, you cannot cut corners. In the test method, make the calls in the order that they will occur in the actual use-case/user story.

Comment: you don't need a commit to see persistent data from a query in the same transaction - you just need a flush() to force the inserts to execute.  Then subsequent selects will see that data, as long as they're using the same underlying connection.